# django jeditable not working

Tags: django, jeditable

PLease i need your help, i'm trying to use jeditable to edit a field on a table inside {% for in %}.

**editable DIV:**

```
<td><div class="edit" id="{{ c.id }}">{{ c.name|safe }}</div></td>
```

**jeditable code:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.edit').editable('/categoryedit/{{ c.id }}/', {
        style: 'display: inline'    
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Url:**

```
url(r'^categoryedit/(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'pos.views.CategoryEdit'),
```

**View:**

```
def CategoryEdit(request, category_id):
  id = request.POST.get('category_id', '')
  value = request.POST.get('value', '')

  categoria = Category.objects.get(pk=id)
  categoria.name = value
  categoria.save()

  return HttpResponse(escape(value))
```

Comment: What is your specific problem? Not just "not working".

Comment: the field become editable, but not saving changes to database and when the field lost focus also lost changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution :** The problem was that the editable DIV was inside a {% for %} bucle and in that case is needed to use .each en the Javascript like this...

```
$('.edit').each(function(){
                $('.edit').editable('/categoryedit', {

                });
            });
```

and is not necessary to pass the parameters in the url ("/category/1") instead is better to get the parameters using ...

```
c_id = request.POST.get('id')
```

**the View must be like this:**

```
def CategoryEdit(request):
if request.is_ajax():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        txt = request.POST.get('value')
        c_id = request.POST.get('id')

        categoria = Category.objects.get(pk=c_id)

        categoria.name = txt

        categoria.save()

        return HttpResponse(txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add CSRF data to your javascript.  I just ran into this and posted it here:
[Django and JEditable: CSRF error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13019488/django-and-jeditable-csrf-error)

One way to see for sure is to use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and look at the ajax response coming back from Django.  (If the CSRF info is missing, the Jeditable AJAX call throws a 403 Forbidden error.)